# Computing the limit of $(\log n)^{0.5}/\log n^{0.5}$

Tags: limits, logarithms, asymptotics

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\log n)^{0.5}}{\log n^{0.5}}$$

I'm really not sure where to begin with this. Are there some basic laws of logs that I should apply first?

Comment: $\lg (a^b) = b \lg(a)$

Comment: do you mean "$\log(n)$" by "$lg.n$"?

Comment: @tired Yes, log base 2

Comment: Is $\frac{x^{0.5}}{x}=1^{0.5}?$ Have you tried that with $x=4$? Your use of $\cdot$ in the expression $\lg\cdot n$, which  I edited out of the question, might indicate some confusion about what $\lg$ is...

Comment: Oh, totally didn't think that through. So instead, I could say that: $\frac{(\lg n)^{0.5}}{0.5\lg(n)}$ = $\frac{1}{0.5(\lg (n))^{0.5}}$ which would then be proof?

Comment: THAT would be a fruitful idea, yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\log n)^{\frac12}}{\log n^{\frac12}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\log n}}{\frac12\log n}$$
$$=2\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\log n}}{\log n}=2\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}=0$$